# Filter through goods and showing available options using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, faceted-search

I have the following filter:

[image]

As you can see here, I have attributes (above each horisontal line) and all existing values for those attributes (below each horisontal line).

Server incoming data from form like this: `["X"=>['1','2', ...], "Y"=>['11','22', ...]]` where X,Y = ids of attributes. 1,2,11,22 = ids of values.

My variant of query is:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/821b25abc1aa4720942a2d9cc7d759bdaee447a9
(Mapping is there too). But it works strange. Aggregations works not with filtered data.

I need to filter through goods and to show number of available options for each value. How to do that? Now when I check some values, I get And, And, And (data is summarized). Number of final set of data is just increasing.

Edit:

I need to have possibility to select several values from each attribute and I need to get data for each value. When I select 1 value from one attribute and one value from another, I need to get documents which match 1 AND 2 value. When I select several values from one attribute and several values from another I need to get at least one pair value (attribute1) and value (attribute2). Also I need to show number of available options for all values.

I've wrote this (and this is works):

```
$query = [
        "query" => [
            "filtered"=> [

                "filter" => [
                    "nested"=> [
                        "path"=> "individual_attributes",
                        "filter"=> [

                            "bool"=> [
                                "must"=> [


                                    $nested


                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],

        "aggs"=> [
            "individual_attributes"=> [


                "nested"=> ["path"=> "individual_attributes"],
                "aggs"=> [

                    "attributes_set"=> [
                        "nested"=> [
                            "path"=> "individual_attributes.attributes_set"
                        ],
                        "aggs"=> [
                            "attributes"=> [
                                "terms"=> [
                                    "field"=> "individual_attributes.attributes_set.attribute_value"
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]

                ]


            ]
        ]

    ];
```

$nested id (`$params = ["X"=>['1','2', ...], "Y"=>['11','22', ...]]`):

```
foreach($params as $k => $v){

  foreach ($v as $sub)
  {

    $nested[] = [
                    "nested" => [
                        "path"   => "individual_attributes.attributes_set",
                        "filter" => [
                            "bool" => [
                                "must" => [
                                    [
                                        "term" => [
                                            "individual_attributes.attributes_set.attribute_id" => [
                                                "value" => $k
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "term" => [
                                            "individual_attributes.attributes_set.attribute_value" => [
                                                "value" => $sub
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ];
    }
}
```

Works perfectly. But I cant choose several values from one attribute.

[image]

Comment: This part is not clear: `Now when I check some values, I get And, And, And` Can you clarify and maybe show some sample documents and what you expect in your results so it's easier for people to recreate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are three kind of filters which you can use. As per the documentation, here is the explanation of all three:
1.) Filtered Query:

> The filtered query is used to combine another query with any filter.
>   In filtered query, filter reduces the number of docs that
>      can be matched (and scored) by the query.

2.) Constant score query:

> A query that wraps a filter or another query and simply returns a
>   constant score equal to the query boost for every document in the
>   filter.

A "constant_score" query says "all docs are equal", so no scoring
   has to happen - just the filter gets applied

3.) Post Filter:

> The post_filter is applied to the search hits at the very end of a
>   search request, after aggregations have already been calculated.

It means that the filter would be applied to search result after the aggregations have been calculated. The hits which you would get would only be filtered and not the aggregation results.

Hence post filters aggregation results does not count the filter where as constant score and filtered query does have aggregation results already filtered. If you are not actually interested in the score of the results and only needs the aggregation values, try wrapping your query/filters in constant score.

Hope this helps.